# Automatically map detected receipt text to an expense category?

Tags: java, android, ocr, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit

I'm building a mobile app that uses Google's ML kit to extract receipt text and detect dates, sum amount, and category.

Among the categories of expenses that my application allows entering are: Bills, House, Eating Out, Food, Health, Transport, Entertainment, etc..

For example, if the detected receipt text contains "Petrol", I would want to know that the expense category that should be entered is "Transport". If "pasta" is detected, either the "Eating Out" or "Food" categories should be chosen.

Is there any way to solve this problem? Any advice on the general direction is also appreciated.

Comment: Hi, could you set up a dictionary to map these keywords->category after the text are getting detected with ML Kit text recognition API?

Comment: Thanks, this method might work at first but I don't think that's what I'm looking for, since there could be numerous words related to the Food category, for example: lettuce, mushrooms, chicken, etc, where it's unreasonable to map them manually. I'm looking for a solution that'll be able to map a large amount of terms to a category that is most closely associated with it in an automated manner. Something like multi-class text classification but the number of "columns" here (a.k.a. receipt line items) vary greatly between receipts, notwithstanding the lack of datasets and pre-trained models.

Comment: I see. Then you probably need to train your own model.  You can use TensorFlow Lite Model Maker(Re-train a model (transfer learning), takes less time and requires less data than training a model from scratch) or train a model with TensorFlow and then convert it to TensorFlow Lite.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try, have a good day!  :)